# get the list of files and folders exist in root directory

Tags: android

in my program I need something like file manager to list the files and directories of internal and external memories . for example see the picture below...

[Example of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4orAV.png)

how can I get the root directory

in fact I want to get a list like picture above that include internal and external directory .
thanks

Comment: you have to show what you have done so far along with  what you want although use `Environment` class which give you the path with `getExternalStorageDirectory`

Comment: Unless you are running on a rooted device, what you want may not be possible, particularly on newer versions of Android.

Comment: thanks CommonWare ... I've run RAR app(for extract the RAR files) on my device and my device is not rooted , in this application you can see what I want (picture that I attached and mark two directory named sdcard and storage) I want to create a list like that.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the list of files and folders exist in root directory, like this:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Pictures";
Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
File directory = new File(path);
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
    Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
}
```

Comment: thanks Mohammad , but your code just list the external memory list , as I said I want the root content , which include the external and internal memory.(see the picture attached)